# Разница между pedantic и Wpedantic

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, clang

В чём разница между следующими опциями?

```
target_compile_options(target PRIVATE -pedantic)
target_compile_options(target PRIVATE -Wpedantic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, никакой разницы нет.

Описание у этих этих флагов в [мануале GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) одно на двоих.

Comment: Для `gcc` согласен. Но в [мануале clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) вижу только `-pedantic` без `-Wpedantic`. Значит ли это, что конфигурация с `-pedantic` включит данную опцию для обоих компиляторов, а с `-Wpedantic` -- только для `gcc`?

Comment: @kqq Проверил на https://gcc.godbolt.org/ - флажок работает. У них мануал не особо хороший: упоминается `-W<warning>`, но чему может быть равно `<warning>` - не написано.

Answer (score 1):

Если немного копнуть документацию по старым версиям gcc, то можно найти что в [4.7.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-252) ещё не было `-Wpedantic`, а вот в [4.8.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-260) он уже появился как синоним для `-pedantic`.

В репозитории gcc удалось нарыть ещё [такое](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/b7faf40d26cb8a6fc781ef7d10ff952f77d525b2/gcc/common.opt#L335):

> ```
> -pedantic
> Common Alias(Wpedantic)
> ```

Из всего этого можно сделать вывод, что на текущей версии `-pedantic` и `-Wpedantic` - синонимы, однако на старых версиях `-Wpedantic` мог отсутствовать.